# Changing the root password via rescue mode does not work

Tags: server, root, forgot-password, ovh, public-cloud

I have a Public Cloud instance via OVH. I reinstalled my computer without backing up my ssh-key. I also forgot the root password for the server. I do have access to my Public Cloud control panel and rebooted with rescue mode.

However, when I change my root password (via the noVNC console) and then reboot to my Ubuntu disk, the new password is incorrect. 
The `passwd` command returns: `passwd: password updated successfully!`.
But then I can't login as root with the new password after exiting rescue mode.

What am I doing wrong?:

Comment: Perhaps the keyboard layout is different. Try copying and pasting the password instead of typing it.

Answer (score 0):

By default, password login for root and the default user is not possible by ssh. If you used a key, you'll need to replace that key via the Rescue Mode. You can follow that guide to do that : [Replacing your lost ssh key pair](https://docs.ovh.com/gb/en/public-cloud/replacing_your_lost_ssh_key_pair/)

Also, remember that you need to mount your partition containing your OS before doing any modification. The step are well describe in the OVH documentation here : [Put an instance in Rescue Mode](https://docs.ovh.com/gb/en/public-cloud/put_an_instance_in_rescue_mode/)

Answer (score 0):

When you are in rescue mode and you change the password with `passwd`, you change the password for the rescue mode only !

If you want to change you "normal OS" password from the rescue mode, you first need to `chroot` into the partition holding your "normal OS" and then use `passwd` there to change your password:

```sh
$ chroot /mnt/vdb1/
$ passwd
```

More details in the [official doc](https://docs.ovh.com/fr/vps/root-password/)